# Open the last used RibbonTab when the wpf RibbonWindow is loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I **return to the last used RibbonTab** that was in focus when the window was last closed?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable to hold the reference to the `RibbonTab` and listen to the `SelectionChanged` event on your Ribbon object.

```
MyRibbonObj.SelectionChanged += delegate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    RibbonTab rt = ((sender as Ribbon).SelectedItem as RibbonTab);
    MyReferenceToRibbonTab = rt;
}
```

This way you keep track of the latest selected `RibbonTab` within your `Ribbon`.

PS: code might needs tweaks. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a setting `LastRibbonTab`

Save the last tab used in `MainWindow_Closed`

```
MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.LastRibbonTab = (MyRibbon.SelectedItem as RibbonTab).Header.ToString();
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Select the last tab in `MainWindow_Loaded`

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Init();
    foreach (RibbonTab r in MyRibbon.Items)
        if (r.Header.ToString() == Properties.Settings.Default.LastRibbonTab)
        {
            MyRibbon.SelectedItem = r; 
            break;
        }
}
```